# convert bits to sound

Tags: audio

i want to convert bits of data to sound, for example 1010 to beep-nobeep-beep-nobeep.how can i compress more bits in it

Answer (score 2):

You can encode a lot of information into sound by using a [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Comment: I think that using Fourier transforms you need the whole range of frequencies, and not just beep (single tone...)

Comment: @Dani You are right, but if the OP is limited to "beep" and "no beep" of equal lengths, he already has an optimal encoding. My answer is slightly tongue-in-cheek, but since the question is a little fuzzy, why not assume the best conditions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use pattern,  assume longbeep means the beginning of a pattern ID and than beep the pattern id, end it with another longbeep.
(If I understood your question...)

or - you can compress the data using a compression library and beep the results...
and then uncompress...

Answer (score 0):

Speech coding does exactly what you are referring to in old FAX machines and TTY terminals, 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_device_for_the_deaf and 3GGP has a standard which described some of the most efficient methods.  http://www.qtc.jp/3GPP/Specs/22226-700.pdf

In simple terms you want the encoded message to be played out or recorded with current audio equipment so the resulting signal after encoding with 0,0, 1 ,1 0,1 sequence should be able to be compatible with the audio equipment that is what these encoders/decoded do.